# How to call an object not from a file I use require.js

Tags: requirejs

I call to object AjaxForm on my html page

```
<script>
        require(['app', '/assets/build/js/app/ajaxform.js'], function (a) {
            a.AjaxForm.initialize({$_modx->getPlaceholder('AjaxForm.params')});
        });
</script>
```

But I get error

```
Cannot read property 'AjaxForm' of undefined
```

My ajaxform.js file

```
define('app', ['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    var AjaxForm = {
        initialize: function (afConfig) {

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.jGrowl.defaults.closerTemplate = '<div>[ ' + afConfig['closeMessage'] + ' ]</div>';
            });
```

.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this:

```
requirejs(["app", "app/ajaxform"], function () {
    require(['ajaxform'], function (e) {
        e.initialize({$_modx->getPlaceholder('AjaxForm.params')});
    });
});
```

And in the file ajaxform.js

```
define('ajaxform', ['jquery','jgrowl','jqueryform'], function ($,jGrowl,ajaxSubmit) {
....
return AjaxForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning `AjaxForm`? I think you are missing this:

```
define('app', ['jquery'], function ($) {
    'use strict';
    var AjaxForm = {
        initialize: function (afConfig) {

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.jGrowl.defaults.closerTemplate = '<div>[ ' + afConfig['closeMessage'] + ' ]</div>';
            });
        }
    }

    return AjaxForm;
});
```

Then, in your `require`, you do:

```
<script>
    require(['app', '/assets/build/js/app/ajaxform.js'], function (AjaxForm) {
        AjaxForm.initialize({$_modx->getPlaceholder('AjaxForm.params')});
    });
</script>
```

Hope it helps